# cloud foundry with update-user-provided-service

Tags: java, php, json, cloud-foundry

I am a new in cloud foundry and i want to update my user provided service with 
cf update-user-provided-service command but it gives me JSON error:
my code are:
C:\Users\S>cf update-user-provided-service common_url -p '{"base_url":"myapps.co
m"}'
FAILED
JSON is invalid: invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a windows CMD prompt and it does quotes differently than UNIX shells. Doing this from memory, I'd say that the correct usage for Windows would be, using the uups alias for update-user-provided-service:

```
cf uups common_url -p "{\"base_url\":\"myapps.com\"}"
```